# SQL error code #1452

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create foreign key for my database. My database is for a gym system.

I have the table called ***user***. Within that table I have user_id which is my primary key. 
I have another table call ***member*** within this table I also have user_id which I want to make a foreign key so it relates to my user_id within the ***user*** table.

But i keep getting the following error..

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Gym_System`.`#sql-247a_3c1`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-247a_3c1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`user_id`))

Can anyone help?

Comment: There must be a userid in `members` not present in `user`. Can you run the following: `SELECT * FROM members LEFT JOIN users WHERE users.user_id IS NULL;` (btw is your table then called `member` or `members`?

Comment: Table is called members, and the other table is called user. I ran that statement and received the following error. 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user.user_id IS NULL LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Ah I am sorry, my mistake, should be: `SELECT * FROM member LEFT JOIN user USING (user_id) WHERE user.user_id IS NULL;`

Comment: Thank you, the SQL statement seemed to work. But do you know how I can check? Im using phpMyadmin. So not sure how i check that it is now a foreign for member?

Comment: Well, did my statement return any rows? Because if it did, then those should have been already included in the `user` table and that is your problem.

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Gym_System`.`#sql-247a_3e4`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-247a_3e4_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`user_id`)) 

Just get that error again.